# "Rejected" line of code in merge conflict. Now I can't get it to show up again in merge

Tags: git, merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I'm new to the development world and it's my first question here I'm thankful for constructive input regarding my problem and also my question build-up. Let's get to the point.

I have `Branch A` and `Branch B`. `Branch A` is my feature branch which I'm working on. `Branch B` is only allowed to be merged into. No work is to be done on it.

I worked on `Branch A` and merged into `Branch B`. Some conflicts came up and I solved them. While solving it seems that I have rejected 2 lines of code from my `Branch A`. I deployed `Branch B` and realized that the lines are missing. So I went back and merged `Branch A` again into `Branch B` in the hopes to be able to get the missing lines in there. But it didn't work.

Is there a way to get those 2 lines into `Branch B` without working on it?

I looked for answers but I only find questions and answers regarding the merge conflict itself.

Thank you for reading this far =)

Comment: Is it a personal project that you are free to do as you will or it's something you are sharing with other people?

Comment: @eftshift0 it's not a personal project. That's also why there's a pretty strict rule of "not working on `Branch B`"

Comment: Why not just open a new feature branch to add the missing lines?

Comment: @matt should I open a new branch from `Branch B` in this case? It does have everything I want besides the 2 lines.

Comment: Totally, why not? There's a bug in Branch B, make a branch to fix it, merge that branch, done.

Comment: By the way, if you're new to Git, you might enjoy my introductory article, https://www.biteinteractive.com/picturing-git-conceptions-and-misconceptions/

Comment: @matt thank you! It's late where I'm from. I will wait for the ok of the person in charge, since I'm still very new. I will update you in the morning when I get the green light.

Comment: @matt regarding your article -> That's actually perfect timing. I had a couple of issues regarding git today and decided that I will learn about it in the following days and weeks =)

Comment: @matt good thing I waited for the person in charge. The project surroundings I am working in this approach would apparently cause issues. It seems like in this case it's preferred to do the commit straight on the target branch.

Answer (score 0):

> So I went back and merged Branch A again into Branch B in the hopes to be able to get the missing lines in there. But it didn't work.

Git considers all (relevant) changes from the source branch at the time the merged was done to be included in the destination branch after merge is done. That includes the two missing lines, which the merge commit now implicit records as not wanted. Later merges of the source branch will not re-consider content from before the last commit.

What you can do however is to create a new (temporary) branch from the commit on the destination branch right before the merge was done. Then you can merge into that branch. That should then result in a merge that includes those two missing lines (and possibly more). The result from that operation can then be brought in to the destination branch.

---

So a concrete example. Hard boiled eggs recipe, the `main` branch adds text content, the `formatting` branch changes markdown formatting and adds an image link. The `main` branch is merged into the `formatting` which trigger a merge conflict, and in resolving those I deliberately chose to "lose" two lines with tips on how to avoid eggs cracking.

Gitk screenshot: [image: Gitk screenshot]

After this first merge, subsequent merges of `main` into `formatting` will not bring in those two lost lines because as far as git is concerned, **all** changes on the `main` branch are incorporated.

So to bring those "lost" changes back in I would do the following:

## Step 1

Create a new branch from the commit from before the merge commit on `formatting`,

```bash
$ git branch merge_fix merge-commit^
$ git checkout merge_fix
$
```

## Step 2

(This step is strictly speaking optional, but it will reduce the amount of conflicts that can arise). Bring in the changes done in the merge commit without recording it as a merge commit.

```bash
# Make the worktree identical to the content of commit tagged "merge-commit".
$ git diff HEAD merge-commit | git apply -
$ git add eggs.md                                # The only file changed.
$ git commit -m "Content from merge-commit"
$
```

## Step 3

Merge `main` into `merge_fix`. This will still result in the same conflicts for the two lines as when the original merge that was done (although less conflicts overall with step 2 done).

This time I resolve the lines correctly to have them included (and changed to markdown list entries).

```bash
$ git merge main
$ git resolve-conflict-using-kdiff3    # https://github.com/hlovdal/git-resolve-conflict-using-kdiff3
$ git diff --cached | sed 1,4d
@@ -7,6 +7,8 @@
 
 ## Instructions
 
+* Pinch a hole in the top of the eggs to avoid that it cracks during boiling.
+* If the eggs have room temperature when starting, there is less chance of cracking.
 * Put enough water in the pot to completely cover the eggs.
 * Put on heat and wait for the water to start boiling.
 * Put in the eggs.
$ git commit
$
```

Now the latest commit on `merge_fix` branch contains all the missing changes we want to bring back.

## Step 4, alternative 1

Conceptually, the simplest thing to do is perhaps then to just merge it into `formatting`,

```bash
$ git checkout formatting
$ git merge merge_fix
$ git resolve-conflict-using-kdiff3    # https://github.com/hlovdal/git-resolve-conflict-using-kdiff3
$ git commit
$ git b -d merge_fix
```

however you still get merge conflicts on this and the history from this becomes rather messy:

[image: Screenshot after merge of branch merge_fix]

## Step 4, alternative 2

So a better way that creates cleaner history is the following:

```bash
$ git branch formatting_fix merge-commit 
$ git checkout formatting_fix 
$ git diff HEAD merge_fix | git apply -
$ git add eggs.md                            # The only file changed.
$ git commit -m "Merge in missing changed from main branch"
# Chose one of the following rebases depending on your preference
$ git rebase formatting_fix formatting       # I chose this one.
$ git rebase formatting formatting_fix
$ git checkout formatting
$ git branch -d formatting_fix
$
```

[image]

So with this you get one clean commit with the missing lines added. Strictly speaking it is a merge commit and should have a second parent added (this should be possible so you can look into that if you want to).

## Step 5, optional

However with the state from step 4.2 it is quite easy to actually fix the original merge commit to not have the lines missing in the first place. To do that run an interactive rebase where you select `fixup` for the commit created in step 4.2 and amend the merge commit:

```bash
$ git rebase --interactive --rebase-merges merge-commit^
# Change pick to fixup for the commit from step 4.2 (and move the line if you
# chose "git rebase formatting formatting_fix"). See text example below.
$
```

```
label onto

# Branch main
reset 17502fa # Initial text
pick 73bc309 Add tips
pick 730edf1 Add Ingredients and Instructions sections
label main

reset onto
merge -C 78b538e main # Merge branch 'main' into formatting
fixup 3bb3385 Merge in missing changed from main branch
pick 1f1e9b7 Add image link
```

This gives the following history.

[image: after interactive rebase]

At this point there is no need to keep the `merge-commit` tag and `merge_fix` branch, so those can be deleted.

Comment: Creating a new branch on that commit and trying to merge it won't help as it's the same thing in git. You are trying to merge a _commit_ that is already merged.

Comment: Git operates on differences and not necessarily what commits that contribute to the final difference between two things. The commits from the source branch are partially merged (since at least two lines are missing). Doing an additional merge of (just) the commits from the source branch from before the merge commit will then have those two missing lines included in the difference, and it will be included in the new merge difference.

Comment: Oh, but when you say _source_ branch you mean `branchB`? Then you are onto something.

Comment: _however_, just doing that merge, you haven't solved the problem. How do you get this change to be _appliable_? Say, complete the recipe (I think @matts proposal is the simplest thing... at least for a very small thing. If we were talking about hundreds of lines missing, then something like this you are proposing might be the way to go... at least, for starters).

Comment: Thanks for your answers hlovdal and eftshift0. The route you described hlovdal seems to be quite out of my knowledge zone. I guess will try the new branch like matt suggested. (Apparently I can't @ more then one person, so I will @ none ^^)

Comment: The last paragraph is confusing, particularly, "Then you can merge that branch." Are you suggesting redoing the merge? In that case I think you would have to: 1.) Redo the merge of `branch-A` into `branch-B~1` and resolve the conflicts again, this time keeping the 2 lines that were resolved incorrectly last time. And then 2.) Merge that new corrected merge commit into `branch-B`, or otherwise force push. If that's what you meant, I would say just branching off of `branch-B` and adding the 2 lines in would be easier. (And your answer could use some clarification if it did mean all of that.) ;)

Comment: @TTT I have updated the original answer and also added a concrete example.